# Accessing IntelliJ IDEA functionality via API

Tags: api, intellij-idea

I need to be able to add a svn precommit check to ensure that all java files being committed are properly indented - adhering to our project specific settings. We use IntelliJ IDEA 9.0 for our development. I was wondering if it is possibe to directly access IntelliJ IDEA 9.0's indentation functionality via an API so that I can call it from svn pre-commit hook. Any better ideas? (I don't intend to write plugins)

Answer (score 1):

[Commit dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/commit-changes-dialog.html) already has certain **Before commit** actions including **Reformat code**. Just make sure it's enabled. There should be also an API to provide custom actions for this dialog which will be performed by plug-ins. Check the IDEA Community edition source code to see how to use it.